# How to implement Global calendar

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

It would be great if any one would let me know how to implement global calenar in sharepoint 2007.
I m new to sharepoint. Pls tell me step by step.
Thank you

Comment: you should start improving your accept skills...

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Creating SharePoint global calendar](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/01/24/creating-sharepoint-global-calendar.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote an article about using a SharePoint Designer workflow to automatically synchronise lists whenever they are updated. As a calendar is just a list it works on that as well.

As an added advantage, because it is part of a workflow, you can add some conditional logic. E.g. 'only sync to global calendar if field xxxx = yyyy'.

[You can find the artice here](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/12/automatically-synchronise-sharepoint.html). It is written as a step-by-step guide.